# arguments of the sha256 function in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, cryptography, hash-algorithm

In Solidity, I find that the `sha256` function can be used like this `a = sha256(uint b, string c, bool d, ......)` (the arguments can be a combination of different types, and the other types can also be included.)

What does `sha256` do with the arguments of different types?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solidity docs say that `sha256` (and `sha3`, `ripemd160`) arguments are [tightly packed](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#mathematical-and-cryptographic-functions):

> “tightly packed” means that the arguments are concatenated without
>   padding. This means that the following are all identical:
>
> sha3("ab", "c")
>
> sha3("abc")
>
> sha3(0x616263)
>
> sha3(6382179)
>
> sha3(97, 98, 99)

Using the question's example of `a = sha256(uint b, string c, bool d)`,

- if we assign some values like `b` is 31415, `c` is `"abc"`, and `d` is false,
- then `a` would equal `sha256(31415, 6382179, 0)`, which is same as `sha256(0x7ab761626300)`.

---

For completeness, the docs mention that:

If padding is needed, explicit type conversions can be used: sha3(“x00x12”) is the same as sha3(uint16(0x12)).

Comment: What would the following line return :     uint var = sha3("abc","pqr",121);

Comment: @RahulSharma browser-solidity tells me `0xec7bee56c53a0d4df8f2fb29d262d59c29a5896470ad3788c7a89cd70eac82ad`

Comment: Is it the output of sha3 function?

Comment: Yes https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9e144d1bd0def71a1f80053404fe4896  (I forgot to use `constant` but browser-solidity is still able to show the result.)