# How does solidity "tightly packed arguments" work in sha256()?

Tags: solidity, hash

I'm trying to recreate the following Solidity code in python: sha256(x1, y1, x2, y2) where the x's are addresses and the y's are uint256's.

I've installed the correct sha256 library and I can successfully recreate a hash of one argument. But it doesn't work when I try it with multiple arguments, so I think I'm not "tightly packing" the arguments in the same way that Solidity is in sha256().

Here's what I'm trying right now in Python:

```
x1 = 0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
x2 = 0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
y1 = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
y2 = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001

data = x1[2:] + x2[2:] + y1[2:] + y2[2:]
answer = sha256(data.decode("hex"))
```

the result is: 0x4e16b1812b95ddb26d9449dff36d48c85c2d0969f6725b117afc83ab2a354968

but an identical function in Solidity gives me: 0x0549a83cb0b851f2025d3600172681973b9944ab1b157e9fae00984061bce198

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the identical function in Solidity doesn't use `keccak256()` ?

Comment: I checked and I'm definitely using the right hash function because i can hash a single uint and get the same value. It's only when I hash multiple arguments in solidity (like sha256(x1, y1, x2, y2)) where I have trouble getting the same answer

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3715/arguments-of-the-sha256-function-in-solidity

Comment: I have the exact same problem

Answer (score 3):

First, I have to clarify that you stated that the sha3 hash is the result of sha256(x1, y1, x2, y2), but then you tried to calculate sha256(x1, x2, y1, y2). I don't know which of those gave you the result, so I am going to show the solution to both tasks.

**Precognition**

1. the usage of sha3(...) is equal to the usage of keccak256(...) in
   Solidity. In reality, a keccak256 hash of the data is calculated.
2. The usage of multiple arguments inside keccak256(...) is discouraged and will be deprecated in the future.

Cite (https://Solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=abi.encodePacked#abi-encoding-functions):

> Furthermore, keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a, b)) is a more explicit way to compute keccak256(a, b), which will be deprecated in future versions.

This note also leads to another realization. Since *keccak256(a,b)* is equal to *keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a, b))*, we have to find out how the *abi.encodePacked(...)* function operates to finally figure out which data was used for your *sha256(x1,y1,x2,y2)* call.

3. abi.encodePacked(...) packs the arguments into one number.

Cite (https://Solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/abi-spec.html#non-standard-packed-mode):

> Solidity supports a non-standard packed mode where:
>
> no function selector is encoded,
>   types shorter than 32 bytes are neither zero padded nor sign extended and
>   dynamic types are encoded in-place and without the length.
>
> As an example encoding int1, bytes1, uint16, string with values -1, 0x42, 0x2424, "Hello, world!" results in

```
0xff42242448656c6c6f2c20776f726c6421
  ^^                                 int1(-1)
    ^^                               bytes1(0x42)
      ^^^^                           uint16(0x2424)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ string("Hello, world!") without a length field
```

> More specifically, each statically-sized type takes as many bytes as its range has and dynamically-sized types like string, bytes or uint[] are encoded without their length field. This means that the encoding is ambiguous as soon as there are two dynamically-sized elements.

**Solution using Solidity**

After implementing the solution in Python, my results were not equal to your given hash. I was looking quite a long time for my error, but I could not find one. So I had to assume, that the hash you provided could actually not belong to the result of *sha256(x1,x2,y1,y2)* or *sha256(x1,y1,x2,y2)*, which turned out to be the case.

You can execute the following code at https://remix.ethereum.org

```
pragma Solidity ^0.4.7;
import "remix_tests.sol"; // this import is automatically injected by Remix.

contract Test {

    function testPackingAndHashing() public pure returns (bytes, bytes, bytes32, bytes32) {
        address x1 = 0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789;
        address x2 = 0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789;
        uint256 y1 = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001;
        uint256 y2 = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001;
        return (abi.encodePacked(x1, x2, y1, y2), abi.encodePacked(x1, y1, x2, y2), 
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(x1, x2, y1, y2)), keccak256(abi.encodePacked(x1, y1, x2, y2)));
    }
}
```

Executing the code gives me the following results:

> 0: bytes: 0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
>
> 1: bytes: 0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000101234567890123456789012345678901234567890000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
>
> 2: bytes32: 0x8507cc9ba3e98ea475462d270a7c3d1f516850eef73042db8942d7d171164e79
>
> 3: bytes32: 0xb11d6ebcb58892c42346a73b14a0d1422310158ce075b733ad1e23b86309cc8c

**Solution using Python**

The existing Python libraries for Ethereum can be found in the package pyethereum (https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum). They use the package "pycryptodome" (https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/introduction.html) for their keccak256 hash calculations, which I will use in the following example as well.

Python code showing how the get the correct hash for solidities *sha256(x1,y1,x2,y2)* and *sha256(x1,x2,y1,y2)* calls:

```
from Crypto.Hash import keccak
from math import ceil

kec1 = keccak.new(digest_bits=256)
kec2 = keccak.new(digest_bits=256)

x1 = "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
x2 = "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
y1 = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"
y2 = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"

c1 = x1 + x2 + y1 + y2
c2 = x1 + y1 + x2 + y2

c1_byte_count = ceil(len(c1)/2)
c2_byte_count = ceil(len(c2)/2) # same as c1_byte_count of course

# note that Ethereum uses big endian representation for lists of bytes
c1_bytes = int(c1, 16).to_bytes(c1_byte_count, "big")
c2_bytes = int(c2, 16).to_bytes(c2_byte_count, "big")

c1_result = kec1.update(c1_bytes).hexdigest()
c2_result = kec2.update(c2_bytes).hexdigest()

print("Result of old solidity sha3(x1,x2,y1,y2): ", c1_result)
print("Result of old solidity sha3(x1,y1,x2,y2): ", c2_result)
```

Output:

> Result of old solidity sha3(x1,x2,y1,y2):  8507cc9ba3e98ea475462d270a7c3d1f516850eef73042db8942d7d171164e79
>
> Result of old solidity sha3(x1,y1,x2,y2):  b11d6ebcb58892c42346a73b14a0d1422310158ce075b733ad1e23b86309cc8c

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what exactly is your solidity code so it is hard to say what goes wrong, but it works for me doing more or less what you do so I think there might be some problem when you convert you output from solidity (or you are using a different library for the sha256). My python code is:

```
x1 = '0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789'
x2 = '0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789'
y1 = '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'
y2 = '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'
data = x1[2:] + x2[2:] + y1[2:] + y2[2:]
answer = int(hashlib.sha256(data.decode("hex")).hexdigest()[0:2],16)
print answer
```

This prints the first two hex numbers (the first byte) as an integer. Change 0:2 to any 2*n:2*n+2 for the n:th byte. The result here is 190. (note the '' which is absent in your code, without them I get a runtime error. So either it is a typo or perhaps you use a different library for the sha256)

My solidity function is

```
function sh(address a, address b, int x,int y) public constant returns (int){
    return int(sha256(a,b,x,y)[0]);
}
```

which also returns the first byte of the resulting hash (which is a bytes32) as an integer. Again, change [0] to [n] for the nth byte. By calling this function as

```
sh('0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789','0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789',1,1)
```

I also obtain the result 190 for the first byte. All other bytes can also be checked to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it:

Assume your function looks something like this:

```
function yourfunc(address x1, address x2, uint256 y1, uint256 y2) returns(bytes32){
    return sha256(x1, x2, y1, y2);
}
```

testing in remix we can verify that for your input values the output is: "0xbe741f2754a25b3a2f4c469ad8f78db64abc2b54ac309b96d06c41ed6a96b282"

One way to replicate this in python is as follows:

```
x1 = int("0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789", 16).to_bytes(20, "big")
x2 = int("0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789", 16).to_bytes(20, "big")
y1 = int(1).to_bytes(32, "big")
y2 = int(1).to_bytes(32, "big")

hashlib.sha256(x1+x2+y1+y2).hexdigest()
```

which again returns "0xbe741f2754a25b3a2f4c469ad8f78db64abc2b54ac309b96d06c41ed6a96b282".